# Acces Denied: How can I create a powershell script that deploys IIS websites from Visual Studio post build event command line

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, iis

I am trying to use the Web Administration module in a powershell script to deploy a  handful of IIS websites and application pools using the visual studio post build event command line.  When I run the script without using the web administration module the script succeeds, however I get an access denied error when they are included.

1. I have visual studio running as administrator
2. I have tried all sorts of flavor of setting the execution policy, but right now this is what I have (I have tried running both 32 and 64 bit versions of powershell):

   ```
   cd $(ProjectDir)
   C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -NonInteractive -File "SetupLocalEnvironment.ps1" 2> nul
   ```

Looking for some assistance as my research is starting to reach the fruitless point. Thanks!

Here is the powershell script:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration

$FNMAWorkSpaceDirectory = "x"

# Do not edit below 

Remove-Website -Name EDI
Remove-Website -Name WebAPI
Remove-WebAppPool -Name EDIAppPool
Remove-WebAppPool -Name WebAPIAppPool

New-WebAppPool EDIAppPool
New-WebSite -Name EDI -Port 124 -PhysicalPath "thePath" -ApplicationPool "thePool"
New-WebBinding -Name "EDI" -Protocol "https" -IPAddress "*" -Port 125

New-WebAppPool WebAPIAppPool
New-WebSite -Name WebAPI -Port 123 -PhysicalPath "thePath" -ApplicationPool "WebAPIAppPool"


Set-Location Cert:\LocalMachine\My
$certHash = (Get-ChildItem -DnsName "theCertName").Thumbprint


$guid = [guid]::NewGuid()
$Command = "http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:125 certhash=$certHash appid={$guid}"
$Command | netsh

exit
```

Comment: Are you running those commands local to the IIS host?

Comment: Yes they are to the local iis.

Comment: Have you tried stopping the website + appPools prior to removing them?  If you're getting an exception, can you add it to your question?

Comment: I have done iisresets and such.  I don't get an exception there is just an output in the build event that says Access Denied.  When I try to pull the commands out into a regular command prompt window the script runs without issue.  I suspect the issue lies with the commands being run as part of the MSBuild/Build events.

Comment: I never figured this out, I ended up doing this with app cmd instead of powershell.